# Mongodb throwing "exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath"

Tags: mongodb

I have tried installing the config file on MongoDB by doing as follows:

> Mentioning the *dbPath* in the config file(mongod.cfg) and then run *" mongod -config mongod.cfg --install "*.

But it is still showing the same error. I know the datapath can be given manually by doing

> *mongod --dbpath=" location of the data/db folder"*

on every run but it is monotonous. Can anyone explain why am I getting the error in spite of installing the config file or suggest a way to permanently set the location of the data folder?

This is the stack trace that I am getting

```
2019-02-28T23:16:13.487+0530 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling 
TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-02-28T23:16:13.490+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : 
pid=11468 port=27017 dbpath=F:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-P2S6LJI
2019-02-28T23:16:13.491+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: 
Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2019-02-28T23:16:13.491+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.6
2019-02-28T23:16:13.491+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 
caa42a1f75a56c7643d0b68d3880444375ec42e3
2019-02-28T23:16:13.492+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: 
tcmalloc
2019-02-28T23:16:13.492+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-02-28T23:16:13.492+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-02-28T23:16:13.492+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 
2008plus-ssl
2019-02-28T23:16:13.493+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: 
x86_64
2019-02-28T23:16:13.493+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: 
x86_64
2019-02-28T23:16:13.493+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-02-28T23:16:13.496+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in 
initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory F:\data\db\ not found., 
terminating
2019-02-28T23:16:13.496+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to 
close listening sockets...
2019-02-28T23:16:13.497+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-02-28T23:16:13.497+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with 
code:100
```

This is my *mongod.cfg* file  [mongod.cfg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rjHeY-h0qtoFDpCOiDqNdjMABwclMJnb/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You need to change the dbpath option in the config file located in `<install directory>\bin\mongod.cfg`

Comment: I have already edited the _.cfg_ file and installed it but still, get the same error.

Comment: Could you provide step-by-step how you installed MongoDB, the content of your cfg file, and the full error message?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha please see the edit

Comment: The `mongod.cfg` file is using YAML format. Indentation is crucial in a YAML file. Currently the cfg file you posted is not a valid YAML file. Please post your cfg file verbatim with the indentation intact to rule out it was a YAML formatting issue.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha Added the link to the config file

Comment: @KevinAdistambha Did you get where the problem lies?